# How to implement CallKit in real app?

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, push, voip, callkit

I am trying to implement Apple CallKit in my VoIP application. I am using Xcode 9.2, Swift 4.0.3, iOS 10.3. Problem is I do not know how exactly to do this. I have tried to search for tutorial in Web, but I failed to find tutorial based on real system. They all using fake systems, only simulate calls! I have a class which rules with someone third person library which is responsible for the calls. So, if I have incoming call happens, some event goes through observer. Like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name(rawValue: Notifications.Name.transMessage.rawValue), object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
   self.handleLibtransEvents()
}
```

where self.handleLibtransEvents is private function calling calls.
Plus, I have installed working PUSH Notification system in AppDelegate.swift. Like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("NOTIFICATION ERROR: \(error)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let pushToken = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)}).lowercased()
    print("pushToken: \(pushToken)")

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState != UIApplicationState.active {
        // PUSH: Incoming call event!
    }
}
```

So there are two places, I can catch incoming call but I have not any idea how to catch real call through Apple CallKit. I will be thankful for any help, advice, call example. Thanks!
P. S. I have installed all settings correctly.

Comment: callkit demo is available on github , download the code and run on device to understand the functionality .

Answer (score 1):

[CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit?preferredLanguage=occ) is basically a framework to show up a Call UI when ever you receive a voip call or make a new call, So it will do nothing if you pass it a number n assume it will make call, Keep it in mind its only to show a UI for receive call & make call. 
To make calls n receive calls you will need 3rd party services like [Sinch](https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/ios/) and many other.